# Why my wireless mouse doesn't work in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers, mouse

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop but my wireless mouse is not working on it.
I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop but my mouse is working properly on it. my mouse is 2.4 GH Generous
what should I do??

Answer (score 9):

If you are still facing this issue, check the modules or drivers and uninstall/replug the device and see. I had the same issue where the wireless mouse was getting identified as Mosart semi 2.4G wireless but it just would NOT work!!!

And then tried the windows way of troubleshooting - uninstall/re-install drivers (pun intended) all I did was modprobe -r usbhid and plugged the nano receiver with skepticism.....but to my surprise it started to work again. I had spent close to 1-1.5 months trying to get this work and in the end all that was needed was to uninstall the driver :)

#### Summary

1. Unplug dongle.
2. Run `modprobe -r usbhid` on the command line.
3. Plug dongle again.

Comment: this worked for me, also for Mosart 2.4G Wireless

Comment: This don't work for my case, `usbhid` is bultin.

Comment: Worked for `248a:8514 Maxxter` Thanks